# How To Switch Columns In SQL Results

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lets say I have a simple query like:

```
SELECT
    A
   ,B
FROM
    C
```

I will get this result:

```
A|B
---
x|x
```

Without changing the select clause in the query (SELECT A, B), how can I receive a result as follows:

```
B|A
---
x|x
```

######## EDIT

The reason I ask is because I want to do the following but is improper syntax:

```
SELECT A, DISTINCT B
FROM C
```

I truly want the `DISTINCT B` in the first column because it is easier to both look at and find patterns in the results.

Is there a better approach to take?

Comment: You can't.  The first column is always going to be called `A` and the second `B`, because of the `select` clause.

Comment: After your edit: If you move distinct before `A` it's going to return distinct pairs (A, B), not distinct `A`s..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your revised query could be written:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A, B
FROM RBase;
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT B, A
FROM RBase;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subquery:

```
SELECT A, B FROM (SELECT B AS A, A AS B FROM C) AS sq;
```

Obviously the column names won't match but the column content would be swapped.

Comment: I am going to edit the question because there is a reason why I want this.

Answer (score 1):

You don't.  In SQL columns are returned in the order specified by the query.

Unless you're talking about a trick question where you say this qualifies:

```
SELECT
    B
   ,A
FROM (
    SELECT
        A
       ,B
    FROM
        C) D
```

Or unless you're talking about displaying the columns in a different order in your application, in which case that depends completely on your application.

However, in pure SQL, the column order is defined by the query.

Comment: I am going to edit the question because there is a reason why I want this.